# SSL Security Error happens on Excel Macro after server upgrade

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, ssl

Macro (button) on excel can not work after the SQL Server upgrade to SQL Server 2016.

The detailed is: the macro creates the SQL connection string with provider, server and database. After upgrading the server, I changed the server name under the VBA Code. But I get this error:

> Connection failed:
>   SQLSTATE:'08001'
>   SQL server Error:18
>   [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen(SECDoClientHandshake())]SSL Security error.

Thank you for providing your solution in advance!

Comment: try changing your connection string. refer to this page https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Premier-Field-Engineering/Microsoft-Excel-TLS-SQL-Server-8211-Important-Considerations/ba-p/371404

Comment: Thank you, this is what I need! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Excel doesn't support TLS 1.1+

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/core-infrastructure-and-security/microsoft-excel-tls-amp-sql-server-important-considerations/ba-p/371404